# how to join two SELECTS where one needs the calculated output of the other

Tags: sql, sqlite, left-join

```
CREATE TABLE customers_tbl 
(
    cust_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    account_creation DATE, 
    last_ordr_date DATE
);
```

How do I join these two `SELECT`s in SQLite where one needs the calculated output of the other?

This generates a single column calc_date:

```
SELECT 
    DATE(account_creation,'weekday 0','-6 days') as calc_date 
FROM 
    "customers_tbl"
WHERE 
    DATE(account_creation) >= DATE('now','localtime','-364 days')
GROUP BY 
    calc_date
ORDER BY 
    account_creation ASC
LIMIT 50000
```

This computes a single value retention% as function of `calc_date`, which is generated in the first section.

It needs the two columns, `calc_date` and `retention$`:

```
SELECT 
    100 * CAST((SELECT COUNT(*) AS retainedcustcount
                FROM customers_tbl
                WHERE DATE (account_creation) BETWEEN DATE(calc_date, '-21 days') 
                                                  AND DATE(calc_date, 'localtime', '-14 days')
                  AND DATE (last_ordr_date) BETWEEN DATE(calc_date, '-20 days') AND DATE (calc_date)) AS FLOAT) / 
                (SELECT COUNT(*) AS newcustcount
                 FROM customers_tbl
                 WHERE DATE (account_creation) BETWEEN DATE(calc_date, '-21 days') AND DATE(calc_date, '-14 days')) AS "Retention %"
```

Example input:

```
INSERT INTO customers_tbl (cust_id, account_creation, last_ordr_date)
VALUES
("9258266601","12/29/2023","1/8/2023"),
("9739199739","12/29/2023","12/31/2023"),
("4086661710","12/19/2023","12/21/2024"),
("8059106540","12/26/2023","12/26/2023"),
("4087182471","12/27/2023","12/27/2023"),
("9257255250","12/21/2023","1/1/2024"),
("2145378403","12/31/2023","1/2/2024"),
("9258092593","12/21/2023","12/21/2023"),
("6507735098","12/21/2023","1/9/2024"),
("5104070728","12/21/2023","12/21/2023"),
("2245002039","12/22/2023","12/22/2023"),
("5105794996","12/22/2023","12/22/2023"),
("9256678370","12/22/2023","12/22/2023"),
("9254905027","12/22/2023","12/22/2023"),
("9256993084","12/29/2023","1/9/2024"),
("9517751555","12/23/2023","12/23/2023"),
("9255205775","12/23/2023","12/23/2023"),
("5104702809","12/23/2023","12/23/2023"),
("5102400977","12/23/2023","12/23/2023"),
("9257898817","12/26/2023","12/26/2023"),
("9257855978","12/26/2023","1/2/2024"),
("2096092929","12/26/2023","12/26/2023"),
("9257194811","12/26/2023","12/26/2023"),
("9256058676","12/27/2023","12/27/2023");
```

Comment: How should this work? The first query returns two rows, what's the expected output of the whole query?

Comment: Please use standard spelling & punctuation. Also exposition: sentences & paragraphs.

Comment: "join these" "where one needs the calculated output of the other" is not a clear description of how the output is supposed to be as a function of the input. [mre] [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 0):

I changed the format of the dates to make it work for the sqlite3 I'm running.

I added two new customers so that the queries actually find someone today.

```
('8888888888','2023-11-30','2024-01-12'),
('8888888889','2023-11-30','2023-12-10'),
```

Then you can use a WITH to name the first query and use it in the FROM part:

```sql
WITH calcdate AS (
    SELECT DATE(account_creation,'weekday 0','-6 days') AS calc_date
    FROM customers_tbl
    WHERE DATE(account_creation) >= DATE('now','localtime','-364 days')
    GROUP BY calc_date
    ORDER BY account_creation ASC
)
SELECT calc_date, 100 * CAST((
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS retainedcustcount
    FROM customers_tbl
    WHERE DATE (account_creation) BETWEEN DATE(calc_date,'-21 days') AND DATE(calc_date,'localtime','-14 days')
     AND  DATE (last_ordr_date) BETWEEN DATE(calc_date,'-20 days') AND DATE (calc_date)
    ) AS FLOAT
) / (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS newcustcount
    FROM customers_tbl
    WHERE DATE (account_creation) BETWEEN DATE(calc_date,'-21 days') AND DATE(calc_date,'-14 days')
) AS "Retention %" FROM calcdate;
```

I'm not sure it outputs what you expect as you haven't provided the expected output (and as the subqueries found no customers, the result was basically 0/0).

Comment: sorry about missing customer creation dates not being in range.  i actually made the table last week when i originally posed the problem.

so for your suggestion, what would the whole thing look like?   thx much

Comment: Try what I've suggested and see whether it's what you want.

Comment: I pasted in your code.  what i am getting from my live database is one number:  retention%
what i need are two columns
column1 is the series of prior mondays (calc_days) going back 52 weeks.
column2 is the associated retention% corresponding to each monday.

Comment: Then I probably misunderstood your question.

Comment: Then please provide the input data and the expected output.

Comment: Comma-joins are very confusing and considered deprecated, use proper `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @choroba :  many thanks.   I need a day to validate the output but on the surface looks good.   I didn't know my retention rates were so high.   lets see.   give me a day please.

Comment: @choroba:  you did it.   this last code works perfectly, plus I learned something.  thanks much.   Is there a way to credit you with the answer?